Is the icosian game (Hamilton's game) always solvable?
I'm looking at Hamiltonian graphs and wanted to start with the icosian game. The rules to the version I am looking at are as follows:

There is a planar representation of the dodecahedron, each of the
vertices is a hole, there are 20 pegs numbered. Place the pegs in
order. There are two players, player 1 and 2. Let player 1 go first.
Player 1 places 5 pegs/chooses 5 vertices that are adjacent to each other
Player 2 attempts to place pegs such that each pair of pegs numbered consecutively are also adjacent on the board. Peg 20 must
also be adjacent to peg 1 for player 2 to win.

My question is, does it matter which 5 pegs are chosen initially? Is the game always solvable?
Thanks!

It's a bit hard to see how the players choose the numbers of the pegs. Do you mean that player 1 chooses a $5$-vertex path, and player 2 attempts to complete it to a Hamiltonian cycle?

yes - sorry that was confusing - player 1 forms a 5 vertex path

The dodecahedral graph is very symmetric. There are only three distinct types of $5$-vertex paths to be found in it:

A path that goes around a single pentagonal face.
A path where the first four vertices stay on a single pentagonal face, but the fifth vertex is not on that face. (The reverse of such a path can also be classified under the same category.)
A path where no four consecutive vertices are part of the same face; since any three consecutive vertices of any path always share a face, this uniquely describes the path.

To check that all three of these can be completed to a Hamiltonian cycle, just find any Hamiltonian cycle in the dodecahedral graph, and verify that it contains paths of all three types. The MathWorld article on the Icosian game has a number of diagrams you can try this on.

Thank you! I will check the article out.
